# Php mysql script returns Null insead of a "long" value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a simple PHP script :

```
function test() {
    $sql = "select author, synopsis from book";
    $result = mysql_query($sql); // result set   
    while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $arr[] = $rec;
    };
    $data = json_encode($arr);  //encode the data in json format
    echo $data;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to read the result with jQuery, I get ‘"synopsis" : NULL‘. I'm wondering is it because the value of synopsis in the database contains multiple lines?

jQuery code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: "data/book.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function (data) {
            $('div.book').text(data[0].synopsis);
        }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The output of the php :

```
[{"author":"author","synopsis":null}]
```

Responde to @iMx suggestion :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
   ["author"]=>
string(7) "author"
["synopsis"]=>
string(697) "Le patient du psychiatre 
Dekker, un certain Boone, avoue durant les transes dans lesquelles 
le plonge le docteur, qu'il aurait commis une dizaine de meurtres, 
tous plus sordides les uns que les autres. Seulement, une fois sortie de 
cet �tat d'exaltation, l'homme ne se rappelle de rien. D�sesp�r�, Boone fait une 
tentative de suicide rat�e qui le conduit � l'h�pital. Son compagnon de chambre, 
visiblement bien cram� du cerveau, �voque le nom de Midian, un endroit dans le 
d�sert de l'Athabasca o� se regroupent les damn�s de la terre, 
les �tres qui souffrent horriblement. Convaincu de pouvoir y trouver un r
efuge, et ainsi de mettre un terme � ses crimes, il part sur ce lieu �trange..."
 }
```

Maybe there is a problem because of the french characters?

Comment: Please show us your jQuery code and if possible, the JSON encoded content

Comment: can you provide the output of `var_dump($arr)`?

Comment: looks like you have `NULL` value stored in `synopsis` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is an encoding problem. What encoding do your mysql tables have? `json_encode()` accepts only UTF-8 strings and could return `null` on a non UTF-8 strings - maybe it is your problem. Try to convert the strings with `iconv()` or `mb_convert_encoding()` or to set your MySQL query encoding to UTF-8 with `mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')` before your SELECT requests.